# Watchkit - how do I process icons for App Store submission?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, watchkit

I'm trying to upload a beta app that has a watch kit extension. I'm getting errors on three or four icons, that the store doesn't like. I completed the icon matrix:

[image]

for watch and app. I have no warnings, and the app validates locally. I only get the errors after submission to the store. The errors are shown in the second image.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this, and what steps should I take to remedy the issue.. I believe that WK submissions are now being accepted. Finally, I did visit the site mentioned in the error messages.  Maybe I missed it, but I found no mention of icon errors.

Comment: Have you asked in the Apple devforums?

Comment: Please check your Info.plist file. There will be a key for CFBundleIconFiles that require icons for various sizes. If you have filled the xcassets with all the relevant sizes then remove this key from info.plist file.

Comment: I do not have a key by that name -- I do have a section on icons. That header is "Icon files (iOS 5)"

Comment: @stk. Yes, I have asked in the devforum. The watch kit icons are apparently in "a state of flux" -- that was from an Apple engineer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `Images.xcassets`-file in your WatchKit App-Folder. You have to fill this with the right images, not the one in your main app. Additionally, make sure that for every Image Set only 'Apple Watch' is chosen as the image target.

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks. I'm now only stuck with three errors -- invalid icon files in the watch kit extension - 40x40@3x, 60x60@2x, 60x60@3x. I don't have files by this name in the extension, nor in the plist file. Weird. Any where else I should look.

Comment: Set up a test project and try to reproduce it. If you can´t, then someone went the wrong way while you were copying icons everywhere in your main app.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it. In the main app imageAsset folder, while there is space assigned for watch kit icons, leave them empty.

Similarly, in the watch kit extension section imageAsset folder, only list those icons intended for the watch - leave iOS icons empty. Repeat this for the watch kit app itself.

Adjust the three info.plist files to match the icon set for the specific target.

Finally, the WK icons must not have an alpha channel. iTS balks at that.

Comment: Well, after way too much time, I got the icons all fixed. Sent it to Apple, and then got a message that TestFlight isn't working yet with the watch... grrrh

Comment: If you have more problems with generating image assets for iOS (or Android) you can use that web http://makeappicon.com/ :)